# CSS Recursive Menu display sub menu on hover

Tags: css

I have created a recursive menu in angular using ngtemplates.
I want to make menu which displays the sub menu on hover. However, I am having trouble when I exit hover of the main menu, the sub menu disappears.

Here is a sample code structure I was generating.

```css
a+ul {
  display: none;
}

a:hover+ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a>a</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a>b</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a>c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that once you start hovering over the `c` Text you no longer hover over the a. So `a:hover + ul` isn't valid anymore and the ul disappears. To solve this you can put the ul inside a wrapper and adapt the selectors and html like this:

```css
.menu-wrapper>ul {
  display: none;
}

.menu-wrapper:hover>ul {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="menu-wrapper">
      <a>a</a>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div class="menu-wrapper">
            <a>a</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a>c</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below piece of code for the expected output:

```css
a+ul {
    display: none;
}

a:hover+ul {
    display: block
}

#menu a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#menu:hover ul,
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul,
#menu:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">a</a>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">b</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">c</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
nav li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  width: 8vw;
}
nav > ul > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
nav > ul > li ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
nav > ul li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}
nav > ul > li > ul li:hover > ul {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<nav>
  <ul >
    <li> 
     <a>a</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a>b</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><a>c</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```